# Property "CGridView.data" is not defined

Tags: php, database, database-design, yii

I am using Yii framework, I am trying to add something to my database and I get this error:

```
            CException

Property "CGridView.data" is not defined.

C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CWidgetFactory.php(161)

149         if(isset($this->widgets[$className]))
150             $properties=$properties===array() ? $this->widgets[$className] : CMap::mergeArray($this->widgets[$className],$properties);
151         if($this->enableSkin)
152         {
153             if($this->skinnableWidgets===null || in_array($className,$this->skinnableWidgets))
154             {
155                 $skinName=isset($properties['skin']) ? $properties['skin'] : 'default';
156                 if($skinName!==false && ($skin=$this->getSkin($className,$skinName))!==array())
157                     $properties=$properties===array() ? $skin : CMap::mergeArray($skin,$properties);
158             }
159         }
160         foreach($properties as $name=>$value)
161             $widget->$name=$value;
162         return $widget;
163     }
164 
165     /**
166      * Returns the skin for the specified widget class and skin name.
167      * @param string $className the widget class name
168      * @param string $skinName the widget skin name
169      * @return array the skin (name=>value) for the widget
170      */
171     protected function getSkin($className,$skinName)
172     {
173         if(!isset($this->_skins[$className][$skinName]))
Stack Trace
#0  
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CWidgetFactory.php(161): CComponent->__set("data", Document)
#1  
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php(146): CWidgetFactory->createWidget(DocumentController, "zii.widgets.grid.CGridView", array("data" => Document, "attributes" => array("id", "file_id", "timestamp", "description", ...)))
#2  
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php(180): CBaseController->createWidget("zii.widgets.grid.CGridView", array("data" => Document, "attributes" => array("id", "file_id", "timestamp", "description", ...)))
#3  
–  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\private\protected\views\document\view.php(30): CBaseController->widget("zii.widgets.grid.CGridView", array("data" => Document, "attributes" => array("id", "file_id", "timestamp", "description", ...)))
25         'file_id',
26         'timestamp',
27         'description',
28         'content',
29     ),
30 )); ?>
#4  
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php(126): require("C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\private\protected\views\docum...")
#5  
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php(95): CBaseController->renderInternal("C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\private\protected\views\docum...", array("model" => Document), true)
#6  
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CController.php(869): CBaseController->renderFile("C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\private\protected\views\docum...", array("model" => Document), true)
#7  
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CController.php(782): CController->renderPartial("view", array("model" => Document), true)
#8  
–  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\private\protected\controllers\DocumentController.php(56): CController->render("view", array("model" => Document))
51      */
52     public function actionView($id)
53     {
54         $this->render('view',array(
55             'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
56         ));
57     }
58 
59     /**
60      * Creates a new model.
61      * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
#9  
 unknown(0): DocumentController->actionView("13")
#10 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\actions\CAction.php(109): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(DocumentController, array("13"))
#11 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(47): CAction->runWithParamsInternal(DocumentController, ReflectionMethod, array("id" => "13"))
#12 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array("id" => "13"))
#13 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(133): CController->runAction(CInlineAction)
#14 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilter.php(40): CFilterChain->run()
#15 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CController.php(1145): CFilter->filter(CFilterChain)
#16 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\filters\CInlineFilter.php(58): CController->filterAccessControl(CFilterChain)
#17 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(130): CInlineFilter->filter(CFilterChain)
#18 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CController.php(291): CFilterChain->run()
#19 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction, array("accessControl", "postOnly + delete"))
#20 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run("view")
#21 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController("document/view")
#22 
+  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(184): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#23 
–  C:\wamp\www\testdrive - 18-05-2015\public\index.php(18): CApplication->run()
13 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
14 // specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
15 defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
16 
17 require_once($yii);
18 Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
19 ?>
```

I am not sure what goes wrong exactly. I have 4 other tables in my database and this is the only one that it wont work and it gives an error.
Can you maybe explain to me what goes wrong?? is the problem from my database??

Later on it adds the record to the database even if it give an error before.

Comment: Post your Cgridview code admin.php file

Answer (score 0):

[CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) displays a list of data items in terms of a table.

Exception because CGidView not have property 'data'. Class have property 'dataProvider'. Here is an easy example of CGridView. You can use GII for generation examples from your models.

```
// in your view.
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'document',
     // you can't use key 'data' here
    'dataProvider' => $document->search(), // @var Document $document - your model
    'columns' => array(
      'id', 
      // ... other properties
    )
));

// in model Document
public function search()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    //$criteria->compare('one_more_poperty', $this->one_more_poperty);
    ...

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```